# Winform how to run an exe file in a folder without knowing the name?

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok, so im making a program launcher, but the file im trying to run have a random name. Heres my code, it works but when the name changes to something random it will stop working

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Process process = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Files/330637421.exe")
                {
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Files/")
                }

            };
            process.Start();
    }
```

Now its working because my file is called 330637421.exe but it will trow an exception because the file will not exist if it changes the name . Btw it is the only exe file on the Files folder. Is there any way to run every exe file on that folder? also keeping the workingdirectory

Comment: Use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0

Comment: Please write more about "keeping the working directory". You mentioned something about it in the comments of the only current answer, so it seems to be something important.

Comment: Yes, the exe file i want to open uses other files on the same /Files/ directory, if it dont detect them it crashes. If i do a  process.Start("File_location"); it shows a loading cursor for a second and nothing happens because it dont detect the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example grabbing the first returned file from `Directory.GetFiles()`:

```
String folder = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Files");
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(folder))
{
    String executable = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.exe").FirstOrDefault();
    if (executable != null)
    {
        Process process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executable)
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                WorkingDirectory = folder
            }
        };
        process.Start();

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No .EXE found in the ../Files Folder!");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No ../Files Folder Exists!");
}
```

Comment: OMG thank you a lot!! it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0) method to get the file. But you have to be careful if there are multiple files in this path. Then you can use pattern to get the particular file.

You can use the required overloaded method mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: ok, sorry im new to this. I did that but i dont know how to get the current directory working. I need it because the exe file i want to open uses other files in the same folder. It tries to open but it cant because of that, heres my code right now
`
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Files/", "*.exe");
            
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                Process.Start(file);
            }
        }
`